# Is it possible to make specific posts editable by all authors?

Tags: users

I have a Q&A site in which people can ask experts different questions. Some questions are addressed to a specific expert so I insert the post under their authorship. However, there is also a General option which should allow all the experts to answer the question.

Is there a way to open specific posts to all users which has a role of author?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the [RoleScoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) plugin to allow certain people to edit a page or a post. You can also set it to let people (or roles) edit a page or post if it is under a certain category. It's pretty good, and pretty easy to operate. You would just select the page/post/category and then select who has access to edit it (either my username or a whole role)

It is also free, if you want more features there is a paid version called "Press permit" although, [RoleScoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) has suited my needs well and the code is still kept up on.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. However, RoleScoper seems like a bit of an overkill. I hope there is a simpler solution